# Toggle keyframe in CSS after pressing a button?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Is there any way to start a animation after I press the button using CSS? 
I have seen some solutions but you have to use JS which I don't know how to do.
So what my idea is that you go on website, and then when you press the button "show more", the 5 columns slide out like they do now. Then when u press it again, they slide down. 
Here is the code if you want to visualize what I am talking about.

```css
html, body {margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden}
#show-more
{
    background: #1594e5;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: calibri; 
    display: block;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 140px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.container
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
img 
{ 
    max-width: 100%; 
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 33%;
    
}
.obj1
{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(136, 44, 44);
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    animation: slide-top 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.obj2
{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(104, 56, 92);
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    animation: slide-top 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.obj3
{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    animation: slide-top 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.obj4
{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(42, 75, 148);
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    animation: slide-top 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
    animation-delay: .7s;
}
.obj5
{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(72, 114, 48);
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    animation: slide-top 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
    animation-delay: .9s;
}
.obj6
{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(119, 39, 112);
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    animation: slide-top 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
    animation-delay: 1.1s;
}
@keyframes slide-top 
{
    0% {transform: translateY(0);}
    100% {transform: translateY(-100%);}    
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="obj1">
 
    </div>
    <div class="obj2">
        
    </div>
    <div class="obj3"></div>
    <div class="obj4"></div>
    <div class="obj5"></div>
    <a id="show-more">Show More</a>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using javascript and css

First you have to seperate the animation into a new class, add an additional class to your object elements, and add a default animation "slide-down":

```
CSS: 
.start-animaton {
    animation: slide-top 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

.my-obj {
    animation: slide-down 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
}


@keyframes slide-down {
    0% { transform: translateY(-100%); }
    100% { transform: translateY(0); }
}

HTML :
<div class="my-obj obj1"></div>
<div class="my-obj obj2"></div>
<div class="my-obj obj3"></div>
<div class="my-obj obj4"></div>
<div class="my-obj obj5"></div>
```

Then add a javascript that will toggle the class 'start-animation' on your objects when you click a button

```
    document.querySelector('#show-more').addEventListener('click', function() {

        var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.my-obj');
        var arrElements = Array.from(elements);
        var delay = 100;

        arrElements.forEach(function(e) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                e.classList.toggle('start-animaton');
            }, delay);
            delay += 300;
        });

    });
```

here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gadawag/1ny9v6hr/25/

Comment: Thank you for the help. I appreciate it so much, but have one more question. 
How can I change the code so when I refresh page the animation doesn't start but it is still invisible until I press the button?

Comment: Here, you may check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/gadawag/1ny9v6hr/39/

This time i used transition instead of animation, because the animation will fire the "from" and "to" which makes the animation visible on start up.